# How to add and remove users from multiple checkboxes by click on "Add" and "Remove" button in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
demoApp.controller('QaController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.teams = [
      {id:1, name:'Chinmay Sahu'},
      {id:2, name:'PHP Chinu'},
      {id:3, name:'Sanjib Pradhan'}
    ];
    
    $scope.myTeams = [
      {id:1, name:'Chinmay Sahu'}
    ];
    
    $scope.add = function() {
            angular.forEach($scope.teams, function(val, key) {
                if (val.checked == true) {
                    if ($scope.myTeams.length > 0) {
                        var dat = $scope.myTeams.find(function(o) {
                            return o.user_id === val.id;
                        });
                    } else {
                        var dat = {};
                    }
                    if (dat) {
                        $scope.myTeams.push({user_id: val.id, name: val.name});
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        $scope.remove = function() {
            
        };
    

    $scope.submit = function() {
        
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content middlealigen col-sm-12" ng-controller="QaController">


<div class="col-sm-4" style=" width: 30%; float: left; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="empList in teams">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="empList{{$index}}" ng-model="empList.checked">
                <label for="empList{{$index}}" ng-bind="empList.name"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="width: 30%; float:left; text-align: center; padding: 15px">
    <div class="col-sm-12 m-b">
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" type="button" ng-click="add()">Add&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="remove()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 grey-bg" style="width:30%; float:lfet; background: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="myteam in myTeams">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="member{{$index}}">
                    <label for="member{{$index}}" ng-bind="myteam.name"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
                    <select class="privacy" ng-model="myteam.privacy">
                        <option value="">Select Privacy</option>
                        <option value="1">Public</option>
                        <option value="2">Private</option>
                        <option value="3">Hidden</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




        </div>
    </body>
```

### My  page looks

[image]

I have posted my sample code. I have 3 users(static) and my team having 1 user. I want to add left box to right box and remove left side if user in my team. Currently I found one user in my team so that user should not show in my users list. eg. - I have an user name `PHP Chinu` If i check this and click on the `Add >` button this `PHP Chinu` should be remove from left box and this will show in the right gray box.

I have tried many ways. But did not getting any right solution. I want to add and remove user to my team. Please help me.

**NB:** `$scope.teams` and `$scope.myTeams` this two variable contain dynamic value.

Comment: If you're going to remove the element from the left side when you add it to the right side... why initially you have the element *Chinmay Sahu* on both sides?! This is inconsistent with the behavior you're expecting... or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

1. Inconsistent property names ... example mixing use of id and user_id
2. You need to added a checked property to all of your objects
3. Your add function was doing a truthy check on 'dat' before pushing which should be a falsey check

Your resulting code looks like this:

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

demoApp.controller('QaController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.teams = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Chinmay Sahu',
    checked: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'PHP Chinu',
    checked: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sanjib Pradhan',
    checked: false
  }];

  $scope.myTeams = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Chinmay Sahu',
    checked: false
  }];

  $scope.add = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.teams, function(val, key) {
      if (val.checked === true) {
        val.checked = false;
        var dat;
        if ($scope.myTeams.length > 0) {
          dat = $scope.myTeams.find(function(o) {
            return o.id === val.id;
          });
        }
        if (!dat) {
          $scope.myTeams.push({
            id: val.id,
            name: val.name
          });
        }
      }
    });
  };
  
  $scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.myTeams.reduceRight(function(acc, team, index, object) {
      if (team.checked === true) {
        object.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }, []);
  };

  $scope.submit = function() {

  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-content middlealigen col-sm-12" ng-controller="QaController">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style=" width: 30%; float: left; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
      <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="empList in teams">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="empList{{$index}}" ng-model="empList.checked">
            <label for="empList{{$index}}" ng-bind="empList.name"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="width: 30%; float:left; text-align: center; padding: 15px">
      <div class="col-sm-12 m-b">
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" type="button" ng-click="add()">Add&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="remove()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 grey-bg" style="width:30%; float:lfet; background: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
      <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="myteam in myTeams">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" id="member{{$index}}" ng-model="myteam.checked">
              <label for="member{{$index}}" ng-bind="myteam.name"></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
              <select class="privacy" ng-model="myteam.privacy">
                <option value="">Select Privacy</option>
                <option value="1">Public</option>
                <option value="2">Private</option>
                <option value="3">Hidden</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An observation here: A checked property doesn't need to be added to all objects since when each element is clicked in the checkbox the property is created dynamically.

Comment: @lealceldeiro - that's true but I thinks it cleaner to have the property preexist rather than have it added dynamically ... a matter of personal preference really.  If it doesn't exist the 'if (val.checked === true)' would need to be changed to 'if (val.checked)'

Comment: @jbrown Remove button not working properly. Can you please check your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. On left side, show only the item not in `myTeams` list - used `Array.prototye.filter` and `Array.prototype.some` to filter out the list
2. while adding, get the checked item from the filtered list and add copy of the object to `myTeams` list
3. while removing, filter unchecked values from `myTeams` list and assign it back to `myTeams` list.

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
demoApp.controller('QaController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.teams = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Chinmay Sahu'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'PHP Chinu'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Sanjib Pradhan'
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.myTeams = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Chinmay Sahu'
  }];
  
  $scope.getTeams = function(){
    return $scope.teams.filter(function(team){
      return !$scope.myTeams.some(function(sTeam){
        return sTeam.id===team.id;
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
    var selectedList = $scope.getTeams().filter(function(team){
      return team.checked;
    }).map(function(team){
      team.checked = false;
      team.privacy = '';
      var _copy = angular.copy(team);
      return _copy;
    });
    
    $scope.myTeams = $scope.myTeams.concat(selectedList);
  };
  
  $scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.myTeams = $scope.myTeams.filter(function(team){
      return !team.checked;
    });
  };


  $scope.submit = function() {
  
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-content middlealigen col-sm-12" ng-controller="QaController">


    <div class="col-sm-4" style=" width: 30%; float: left; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
    <i ng-if="!getTeams().length">nothing to select</i>
      <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="empList in getTeams()">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="empList{{$index}}" ng-model="empList.checked">
            <label for="empList{{$index}}" ng-bind="empList.name"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="width: 30%; float:left; text-align: center; padding: 15px">
      <div class="col-sm-12 m-b">
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" type="button" ng-click="add()">Add&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="remove()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 grey-bg" style="width:30%; float:lfet; background: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
      <i ng-if="!myTeams.length">nothing added</i>
      <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="myteam in myTeams">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" id="member{{$index}}" ng-model="myteam.checked">
              <label for="member{{$index}}" ng-bind="myteam.name"></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
              <select class="privacy" ng-model="myteam.privacy">
                        <option value="">Select Privacy</option>
                        <option value="1">Public</option>
                        <option value="2">Private</option>
                        <option value="3">Hidden</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep consistency in your **id**, so when comparing in the **find** method it can find the right object (`o.id === val.id`).
Also pay attention to the forEach method, you will have problems if you **mutate and also iterate** over the same object, so It's better to use a temp variable.
e.g.

```
const app = angular.module('some',[])
app.controller('ctr',['$scope', function($scope){  
   $scope.teams = [
      {id:1, name:'Chinmay Sahu'},
      {id:2, name:'PHP Chinu'},
      {id:3, name:'Sanjib Pradhan'}
    ];

    $scope.myTeams = [
      {id:1, name:'Chinmay Sahu'}
    ];
     $scope.add = function() {   
            var aux = Object.assign({},$scope.teams);
            angular.forEach(aux, function(val, key) {
                if (val.checked == true) {                  

                      var dat = $scope.myTeams.find(function(o) {
                            return o.id === val.id;
                       });
              var index = $scope.teams.findIndex(function(o){
                          return o.id === val.id
                      });


                      $scope.teams.splice(index,1);                  
                  if(!dat){
                      $scope.myTeams.push({id: val.id, name: val.name});
                  }

        }


            });
        };

        $scope.remove = function() {
          var aux = Object.assign({},$scope.myTeams);
          angular.forEach(aux, function(val, key) {              
                if (val.checked == true) { 


                      var dat = $scope.teams.find(function(o) {
                            return o.id === val.id;
                        });

                      var index = $scope.myTeams.findIndex(function(o){
                          return o.id === val.id
                        })

                      $scope.myTeams.splice(index,1);
                      if(!dat){                           
                        $scope.teams.push({id: val.id, name: val.name});
                      }                      
                    }

            });

        };


    $scope.submit = function() {

    };
}]);
```

See the complete [example](http://codepen.io/Hosar/pen/JWLZJE?editors=1010).
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

demoApp.controller('QaController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.teams = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Chinmay Sahu',
    checked: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'PHP Chinu',
    checked: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sanjib Pradhan',
    checked: false
  }];

  $scope.myTeams = [];

  $scope.add = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.teams, function(val, key) {
      if (val.checked === true) {
        var dat;
       
          dat = $scope.teams.find(function(o) {
            return o.id === val.id;
          });
        
    
          $scope.myTeams.push(dat);
          $scope.teams.splice( $scope.teams.indexOf(dat), 1)
        
      }
    });
  };
  
  $scope.remove = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.myTeams, function(val, key) {
      if (val.checked === true) {
        var dat;
        
          dat = $scope.myTeams.find(function(o) {
            return o.id === val.id;
          });

        
        $scope.teams.push(dat)
        $scope.myTeams.splice( $scope.myTeams.indexOf(dat), 1)

      }
    });
  };


  $scope.submit = function() {

  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-content middlealigen col-sm-12" ng-controller="QaController">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style=" width: 30%; float: left; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
      <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="empList in teams">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="empList{{$index}}" ng-model="empList.checked">
            <label for="empList{{$index}}" ng-bind="empList.name"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="width: 30%; float:left; text-align: center; padding: 15px">
      <div class="col-sm-12 m-b">
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" type="button" ng-click="add()">Add&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="remove()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 grey-bg" style="width:30%; float:lfet; background: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid #e7eaec; padding-bottom: 10px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
      <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="myteam in myTeams">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" id="member{{$index}}" ng-model="myteam.checked">
              <label for="member{{$index}}" ng-bind="myteam.name"></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info radio-inline">
              <select class="privacy" ng-model="myteam.privacy">
                <option value="">Select Privacy</option>
                <option value="1">Public</option>
                <option value="2">Private</option>
                <option value="3">Hidden</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Some trouble while add all and remove all.